# Trouble connecting to ESP8266 NodeMCU Server

Tags: http, lua, wifi, nodemcu, esp8266

I have been having trouble connecting to my ESP-01 Wifi module running NodeMCU. I have set up a simple server, but whenever I try to connect to the IP Address via my browser, my browser times out.
I know I am making connection to the device because I can see the connection data being output from the module. However, the browser never connects to the device. I have been working on this for awhile with several code alterations and have been getting no luck. Here is the code I am running for the server (it comes straight from the NodeMCU documentation):

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("SSID","password")
wifi.sta.connect()

srv=net.createServer(net.TCP) 
srv:listen(80,function(conn) 
    conn:on("receive",function(conn,payload) 
    print(payload) 
    conn:send("<h1> Hello, NodeMcu.</h1>")
    end) 
end)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know nothing about NodeMCU but that is not a proper http server. For it to properly work with a browser, it should return some headers.

You can try to close the connection after sending the response. Try the following:

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("SSID", "password")
wifi.sta.connect()

srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload)
        print(payload)
        local response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n<h1> Hello, NodeMcu.</h1>"
        conn:send(response, function()
            conn:close()
        end)
    end)
end)
```

You could also study the code of [this http server](https://github.com/marcoskirsch/nodemcu-httpserver).